# Draw Lorenz attractor from Point3f array in Java 3D 

Tags: java, graphics, 3d, drawing, java-3d

I have computed the values of the points I need to draw and I put them in a Point3f array. I have 526 435 points. The next step is to draw the points one after another so that it would look like a continous line OR to draw lines between the points using LineStripArray. Because I didn't find how to draw point by point, I've tried to use LineStripArray.

I've taken the code from [here](http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/java3d/how-to-draw-lines-with-java3d.html) and I've changed the content of the method "createLineTypes" with the following code:

```
    Group lineGroup = new Group();

    Appearance app = new Appearance();
    ColoringAttributes ca = new ColoringAttributes(black, ColoringAttributes.SHADE_FLAT);
    app.setColoringAttributes(ca);

    Computing comp = new Computing();

    //the following row computes the values of the points I want to draw 
    //and it works alright; the points are saved into 
    //**static List<Vector3> computed_values** from  class Computing,
    // where Vector3 class defines a 3D point actually
    comp.do_the_job();    

    Point3f[] dashPts = new Point3f[Computing.computed_values.size()];
    for(int i = 0; i < Computing.computed_values.size(); i++)
    {
        dashPts[i] = new Point3f((int)Computing.computed_values.get(i).getX(), (int)Computing.computed_values.get(i).getY(), (int)Computing.computed_values.get(i).getZ());

    }
    System.out.print(Computing.computed_values.size());
    int[] a = {Computing.computed_values.size()};
    LineStripArray dash = new LineStripArray(Computing.computed_values.size(), LineArray.COORDINATES, a);
    dash.setCoordinates(0, dashPts);
    LineAttributes dashLa = new LineAttributes();
    dashLa.setLineWidth(1.0f);
    dashLa.setLinePattern(LineAttributes.PATTERN_SOLID);
    Shape3D dashShape = new Shape3D(dash, app);
    lineGroup.addChild(dashShape);


    return lineGroup;
```

The problem is that it only draws 1 vertical line. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution and it's with PointArray. Here it is

```
    Group lineGroup = new Group();

    Appearance app = new Appearance();
    ColoringAttributes ca = new ColoringAttributes(black, ColoringAttributes.SHADE_FLAT);
    app.setColoringAttributes(ca);

    Computing comp = new Computing();
    comp.do_the_job();

    Point3f[] plaPts = new Point3f[Computing.computed_values.size()];
    for(int i = 0; i < Computing.computed_values.size(); i++)
    {           
        plaPts[i] = new Point3f((float)Computing.computed_values.get(i).getX(), (float)Computing.computed_values.get(i).getY(), (float)Computing.computed_values.get(i).getZ());            
    }

    PointArray pla = new PointArray(Computing.computed_values.size(), GeometryArray.COORDINATES);
    pla.setCoordinates(0, plaPts);
    Shape3D plShape = new Shape3D(pla, app);
    lineGroup.addChild(plShape);

    return lineGroup;
```

**Important: for my application, I had to cast the values to float, not to int as I initially did.**